# Run many instances of the same unix service

Tags: unix

We have an server application we want to run as a Unix/Linux service.

We would like run multiple instances of the application for load sharing and fail over purposes.

Problem I see is that as a unix service only instance of the application should be started.

So asking for advice for on the best solutions for this problem, what is best method for running multiple instances of the application as a Unix service?

I won't go into details about the application architecture because the question is for guidance on uses services and multiple instances of a server.

But an overview of the application architecture is that it is designed so that more than instance can be run at a time on one server. The application serves requests received on message queues, and the messaging broker handles more than one application sharing the same request queue. In addition the database handles many instances updating and reading from it.

Comment: At this general level, it's impossible to give a specific reply. How do clients communicate with servers? Is there a central data store which server instances need to synchronize with? If so, how? Read-only or read/write? Is there a database?

Comment: Thanks triplee, I've added some architecture information to the question.

Comment: inetd, fastcgi, chroot come to mind. But: load balancing / failover doesn't make very much sense on a single physical machine, in general (unless your code is so unreliable that you expect random hangs)